# Angular Material: Mat-Select gets stuck. Works when Resize Chrome window

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an empty Angular 9 project. I imported Angular Material Design. I added mat-select but I somehow when I click on the select item it's not doing anything. Then I noticed, I clicked on the item, then resized the chrome window, the dropdown opened.

```
 <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Cars</mat-label>
    <mat-select>
      <mat-option value="volvo">Volvo</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="saab">Saab</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="mercedes">Mercedes</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="audi">Audi</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

What's the issue?

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: No error, But there's a warning
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.preload.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Comment: it might be a change detection issue. It is difficult to say more without seeing the whole code.

Comment: I don't really have that much code. It's an empty project. I installed Angular Material and imported MatSelectModule in the app module. I cleared all the html and inserted this code. It's rendering fine. But the click event is running after I resize the window or click on a button